# Is it possible to rename a table with the actual timestamp in the tablename within a query

Tags: postgresql, alter

```
select (now();
```

just like so.. but it doesn't works:

```
ALTER TABLE old_name  RENAME TO new_name || select now();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `RENAME` and `SET DEFAULT`

```
ALTER TABLE T
  RENAME old_name TO new_name;
  
ALTER TABLE T
ALTER COLUMN new_name  
  SET DEFAULT now();
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d51acbac1980870938004593984b72bb)